# How can I go about this neural network error?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

I need some help. I am fitting a neural model using neuralnet R page but I have failed to get it right. I keeping getting **[Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments ]**

This my model code

```
nueralModel <- neuralnet(formula = f, hidden = c(4,2), data = dataTrain,
                 err.fct = "ce", act.fct = "logistic",
                 linear.output = FALSE, stepmax = 1000000)
```

[image: The dataset]

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if the formula has different variables than found in your data or if the order of the variables is different than that in your data.

I am not sure what you are using as response and which variables you are including in the model but:

Instead of formula = f, .....

try the long hand version: response = variable1 + variable2 + .....

and see if that helps.